# Дизайн форм на Java

Tags: java

Есть ли инструмент для дизайна форм для Java приложений.
А то в ручную прописывать расположение каждого элемента, долго.

Comment: Разве в идее нет графического редактора? И на эклипс вроде плагин поставить можно.

Comment: В идее он не удобный. Хотел узнать какими пользуются.

Comment: > А то в ручную прописывать расположение каждого элемента, долго.

Привыкайте. На Java вообще писать медленно )

Comment: Как ниже написал Gorets, NetBeans - бесплатная интегрированная среда разработки с визуальным редактором форм.
А вообще, этот редактор никуда не годится... разве что для "однокнопочных" приложений. Если хотите продолжать успешно работать с Java, советую посмотреть видеоуроки по Java Swing (это библиотека визуальных компонентов)

Comment: @metalurgus, как редактор нетБинс совсем неплох, свинг - это просто логическое продолжение awt. а вообще, не стоит зацикливаться на графике джавы, она как не как для веба, потому лучше учить jsp, servlet, spring, а для того что бы разобраться и написать программку с 2мя кнопками полчаса хватит.

Comment: визуальный редактор NetBeans создает много мусора, ИМХО

Comment: Я тут вспомнил какие горы кода надо писать под Eclipse RCP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org)